# div slideshow similar to maxhealthcare.com website

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Actually I am implementing website design similar to the www.maxhealthcare.in. I am confused in the part of the website "Team that Cares" and "Technology". My website is www.mohmand-hospital.com.

Can some one let me know how to find the slideshow and where to find. Here is my code in HTML;

```
<div class="marquee_div">
            <div class="marquee_div_ind">
                <div class="marquee_div_img">
                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/leadership/1.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="marquee_div_detail">
                    <p><span class="color_blue">Hameed Oruzgani</span></p>
                    <p>Heat Specialist</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="marquee_div_ind">
                <div class="marquee_div_img">
                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/leadership/2.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="marquee_div_detail">
                    <p><span class="color_blue">Hameed Oruzgani</span></p>
                    <p>Heat Specialist</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="marquee_div_ind">
                <div class="marquee_div_img">
                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/leadership/3.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="marquee_div_detail">
                    <p><span class="color_blue">Hameed Oruzgani</span></p>
                    <p>Heat Specialist</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="marquee_div_ind">
                <div class="marquee_div_img">
                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/leadership/4.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="marquee_div_detail">
                    <p><span class="color_blue">Hameed Oruzgani</span></p>
                    <p>Heat Specialist</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="marquee_div_ind">
                <div class="marquee_div_img">
                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/leadership/5.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="marquee_div_detail">
                    <p><span class="color_blue">Hameed Oruzgani</span></p>
                    <p>Heat Specialist</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css part;

```
.marquee_div
{
height:auto;
width:100%;
float:left;
/*background-color:#060;*/
}
.marquee_div_ind
{
height:220px;
width:160px;
float:left;
margin:10px;
/*background-color:#666;*/
marquee-direction: left;
-moz-marquee-direction:left;
}
.marquee_div_img
{
width:100%;
height:70%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
/*background-color:#099;*/
}
.marquee_div_img img
{
width:130px;
height:130px;
padding:0px;
margin:10px;
float:left;
/*background-color:#9F9;*/
border:5px transparent solid;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #333;
}
.marquee_div_detail
{
width:81%;
height:30%;
padding:0px 15px;
margin:0px;
float:left;
/*background-color:#990;*/
}
```

Comment: `<?=base_url()?>` this is incorrect php. it should be `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`

Comment: <?=base_url()?> is absolutely fine.